# Getting the total mean brightness deviation of multiple images

Tags: python, image-processing, statistics

I'm working with a camera and acquiring images to analyze. I'm trying to get the following information:

1. Get mean brightness and brightness standard deviation per single picture
2. Get mean brightness and brightness standard deviation per n pictures

My code takes an image and let's the user select an area of interest which it analyzes. When I test the code on plain black/white images where the expected deviation is zero I get unexpected values. I'm having a hard time understanding where my code falls short in terms of the standard deviation calculation, since the brightness is working just fine.

Could anyone please help me find my mistake? Thank you!

Code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageChops
import os
from datetime import datetime
import shutil
import cv2
import numpy as np

center = (0, 0)
radius = (0)
is_dragging_center = False
is_dragging_radius = False

avg_image_round = 10
count = 0
count += 1

def on_mouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global center, radius, is_dragging_center, is_dragging_radius

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        # Check if the mouse click is near the center
        if np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2) < 20:
            is_dragging_center = True
        else:
            is_dragging_radius = True

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        is_dragging_center = False
        is_dragging_radius = False

    elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if is_dragging_center:
            center = (x, y)
        elif is_dragging_radius:
            radius = int(np.sqrt((x - center[0]) ** 2 + (y - center[1]) ** 2))

def pack_data(parent_dir, path):
    path = os.path.join(parent_dir, "images")

    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)


    for a in os.listdir(parent_dir):
        if a.endswith(".jpg"):
            srcpath = os.path.join(parent_dir, a)
            shutil.move(srcpath, path)

    return path

def xray_count(image_path, center, radius):

    image = np.uint16(cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))

    mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask, center, radius, 255, thickness=cv2.FILLED)

    image += 1  # Avoid not counting black pixels in image
    result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

    pixel_count = np.count_nonzero(result)

    brightness_sum = np.sum(result)
    var = (np.std(result))** 2

    avg_brightness = (brightness_sum / pixel_count) - 1 if pixel_count > 0 else 0  # Subtracting back

    print(f"Image: {image_path}")
    print(f"Average brightness per pixel: {avg_brightness}")
    print(f"Standard deviation of pixels: {np.sqrt(var)}")
    print("------------------------")

    return avg_brightness, var

parent_dir = r'C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron'
path = pack_data(parent_dir, r"C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron")
image_files = [os.path.join(path, filename) for filename in os.listdir(path) if filename.endswith(('.jpg'))]

if not image_files:
    print("No '.jpg' files found in the input folder.")
else:
    first_image_path = image_files[0]
    image = cv2.imread(first_image_path)

    scale_percent = 40 
    width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # Initialize the center and radius
    center = (resized_image.shape[1] // 2, resized_image.shape[0] // 2)
    radius = min(resized_image.shape[1] // 3, resized_image.shape[0] // 3)

    # Create a window and set the mouse callback function
    cv2.namedWindow("Adjust the circle (press 'Enter' to proceed)")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Adjust the circle (press 'Enter' to proceed)", on_mouse)

    while True:

        display_image = resized_image.copy()


        cv2.circle(display_image, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(display_image, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)


        cv2.imshow("Adjust the circle (press 'Enter' to proceed)", display_image)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        if key == 13:  # 'Enter' key
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                
    center = (int(center[0] / scale_percent * 100), int(center[1] / scale_percent * 100))
    radius = int(radius / scale_percent * 100)

total_brightness_sum = 0
total_var = 0
 
for i, image_path in enumerate(image_files, start=1):
    avg_brightness, var = xray_count(image_path, center, radius)
    total_brightness_sum += avg_brightness
    total_var += var

    if i % avg_image_round == 0:
        num_files = i 
        print(f"Average Brightness for the last {avg_image_round} images: {total_brightness_sum / avg_image_round}")
        print(f"Average standard deviation: {np.sqrt(total_var / avg_image_round)}")
        print("------------------------")

        total_brightness_sum = 0
        total_var = 0
```

Comment: I presume you realise JPEGs are lossy and things that look black might not be exactly zero - in fact they could be quite large.

Comment: How could I check if that's the case? When I run the program on the potentially loose black image, I get a mean brightness of zero per picture and per n picture which is a good sign. Could the mean brightness work, but the standard deviation not?

Comment: Update: the rounding error is due to the + - 1 for counting the black pixels in the image. Does anyone have a better idea of how I could count the black pixels in a different manner?